# Force data to a specific culture with 'toLocaleDateString'

Tags: javascript, jquery, .net, localization, culture

I have got a date and I like to convert it 'toLocaleDateString' but in the language I like. I am trying to do it, but it always give me the format of the user language(spanish).

```
 var date = new Date();//or any date
 console.log("date: " + date.toLocaleDateString("en-GB");
```

Thanks!

Comment: Which browser are you using? The locale option is not fully supported in some browsers.

Comment: Firefox. It must be on firefox